# Posts 2 Posts plugin: best way to change connection field value?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-posts-to-posts

I have started to use [posts-to-posts](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki) plugin by scribu, and now I need to change vaues for connection fields. Particularly, I've created 'person' and 'piece', connection 'role' in between and defined possible values for role as 'composer', 'conductor' -- but now I think that I need rather 'author', not 'composer'.

Please, how to do that? I could experiment with phpmyadmin, but I wouldn't like to loose anything in progress.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in my case this way hepled: 1) I've replaced `'composer'` with `'author'` in `functions.php` (in that part where connections are being registered) and 2) "edited" data in `${wpdb}_p2pmeta` using phpmyadmin (`UPDATE <yourprefix>_p2pmeta SET meta_value = "author" WHERE meta_value = "composer"` or manually or like that).

Please, backup your data, please test in any way etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you *will* have to use phpmyadmin at this time. Be sure to make a backup beforehand.

Comment: Well, I've replaced 'composer' with 'author' in functions.php and "edited" ${wpdb}_p2pmeta. Everything is ok so far. Thanks!